# Can't get boolean to return false C++

Tags: c++

I am making a program for my C++ course to validate the date using different functions but mostly boolean. My problem is that it won't give false when it is. I have tried it using the else command instead of leaving the return false; without the else but it didn't seem to change anything. Here is the code though:

```
int main()
{
    char Data[80];  
    int Month,Day,Year;    
    int *pMonth,*pDay,*pYear;

    pMonth = &Month;
    pDay   = &Day  ;
    pYear  = &Year ;

    cout << "\n\t\tGive me date : ";
    cin >> Data;

    trial();

    PauseScreen(28,20,3);

    return 0;

}

void SetCursorPosition(int X, int Y)
{
    COORD XY = { Y,X };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),XY);
}

void SetTextColor(int Color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Color);
}  

void ClearScreen()
{
    system("cls");
}

void PauseScreen(int x, int y, int color)
{
    SetCursorPosition(x,y);
    SetTextColor(color);
    system("pause");
}

int InputValues(char *A, int *pM, int *pD, int *pY)
{
    char Buffer[10];

    Buffer[0] = A[0];
    Buffer[1] = A[1];
    Buffer[2] = '\0';
    *pM       = atoi(Buffer);

    Buffer[0] = A[3];
    Buffer[1] = A[4];
    Buffer[2] = '\0';
    *pD       = atoi(Buffer);

    Buffer[0] = A[6];
    Buffer[1] = A[7];
    Buffer[2] = A[8];
    Buffer[3] = A[9];
    Buffer[4] = '\0';
    *pY       = atoi(Buffer);

    return strlen(A);
}

bool ValidateMonth(int A)
{
    if ( A > 0 && A < 13 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;    
}

bool ValidateDay(int day,int month)
{
    if ( month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 9|| month == 10|| month == 12 && (day > 0 && day < 32) )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool ValidateDayTwo(int day,int month)
{
    if ( month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 8 || month == 11 && (day > 0 && day < 31) )
    {   
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void trial()
{
    if(ValidateDay && ValidateDayTwo && ValidateMonth)
    {
        SetCursorPosition(10,10);
        cout << "Date is Valid";
    }
    else
    {
        SetCursorPosition(10,10);
        cout << "You done messed up BALAKI";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which methods don't return false when you expect them to?

Comment: `if (ValidateDay && ValidateDayTwo && ValidateMonth) {...}` You will need to pass some parameters to your calls.

Comment: `if(condition) return true;  else return false;`. Why not just `return condition;`?

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually calling your functions in your if statement. `ValidDay`, `ValidDayTwo`, `ValidMonth`

```
if(ValidateDay && ValidateDayTwo && ValidateMonth)
```

Instead you'll need to invoke the function by passing in arguments

```
if(ValidateDay(somearg1) && ValidateDayTwo(somearg2) && ValidateMonth(somearg2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the functions correctly (well, you actually didn't call them at all) - there are no arguments:

```
if(ValidateDay(?) && ValidateDayTwo(?) && ValidateMonth(?))
```

For example, your `ValidateDayTwo` function takes two parameters.

The fact that the functions' return types are bool doesn't change anything, this doesn't do what you think it does. The name of the function is **a pointer** to the function itself, and you didn't get false as expected, because that pointer is not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ValidateMonth(int A)
{
    if ( A > 0 && A < 13 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

There is no need to say "If the condition is true, return true; otherwise, return false". You can simply return the result of evaluating the condition:

```
bool ValidateMonth(int A)
{
    return A > 0 && A < 13;
}
```